# Javascript return more than once?

Tags: javascript, sorting

please can you help me understand when and under what conditions should I be returning more than once in a statement block?
for example, my code:

```
function checkPositive(arr) {
    return arr.every(function(element) {
        return element > 0;
   });
}
```

why does this only work if I return twice?

I'm confused about how to follow this structure and when to know I should be using them.

Thanks

Comment: You have **two** functions there. A `return` applies to just **one** function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code has *two* functions, and a `return` only applies to the function that `return` is a member of, you need two `return` statements.

It may become more clear when you first define the inner function and then the outer function:

```
function isPositive(element) {
    return element > 0;
}
function checkPositive(arr) {
    return arr.every(isPositive);
}
```

The only difference here, is that we have given a *name* to the inner function (`isPositive`) using a `function` statement.

In this particular case, the `isPositive` function returns whether a single value is positive, while `checkPositive` returns whether *all* values are positive. These functions have a different purpose, and thus are responsible for returning what they are intended to evaluate.